# Nginx offers to download SVG instead of showing it

Tags: svg, nginx, mime

I try to show SVG file in HTML or separate tab but Nginx offers me to download it.
I took normal SVG file which works on another site but not in my server.

Where is a problem?

Here is an example http://proximax.ru/media/content/final/plane2.svg
Also here SVG in HTML http://proximax.ru/index/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  of your image is noted as `application/octet-stream` which a browser can only offer to download as it does not know how to interpret it.

From your `index.html` file it is clear that you were playing around with variations of the MIME-type, and it is unclear whether the standard requires [image/svg](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-SVG-19990412/intro.html) or [image/svg+xml](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#MIMEType) (or standards being what they are, something else entirely).

Comment: I'd go for image/svg+xml, that's what Apache will send by default.

Comment: If you refer to an out-of-date working-draft spec then that's what you get. The SVG 1.1 (and 1.2T) recommendations (read: "most mature/stable spec version") both say "image/svg+xml".

Answer (score 17):

I fixed it.
I added to /etc/nginx/mime.types

```
image/svg+xml svg svgz;
```

Then I checked that server responses correctly

```
wget -O - -S http://proximax.ru/media/content/final/avW30U.svg > /dev/null
..
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
..
```

Also I turned off other virtual spaces for be clear.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I put `default_type  application/octet-stream;` after the `include mime.types;` cause the problem. And simply switch them fixed it. ^_^