# Image url downloads the image instead of displaying it

Tags: html, image, svg

I just switched the site from my working files to the server.

It worked fine when I uploaded it to my portfolio but once it was on the correct domain it stopped working. The image, instead of displaying, just shows up blank so I tried going to it's direct url.

Instead of it working it downloads the image instead of displaying it.

Here is the direct url: [Direct url](http://bestbenefitsclub.com/BBCM/images/login_header.svg)

My tag: `<img src="images/login_header.svg" alt="Alright, lets start finding discounts!" />`

My structure:

```
// root (BBCM)

//// images

////// login_header.svg

//// css

//// js

// end root
```

I have tried:

- /images/url.svg
- the direct url for the image
- BBCM/images/url.svg

It works fine when it's on my [portfolio](http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/BBCM/login.html) but not on the correct [domain](http://bestbenefitsclub.com/BBCM/login.html).

Any ideas? When the image downloads it also displays the correct image so I am a bit lost here.

Comment: has your server got the svg mime type defined?

Comment: I am not sure, on my portfolio I have never made any changes to how the server functions. On the correct domain, I would have to ask our IT guy to see.

Comment: I have the same problem with chrome (43) and a local file `file://path/to/a/file.svg`, and it drives me nuts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your server sending the `.svg` file down with the correct MIME type? It should be `image/svg+xml`.

See [Nginx offers of downoload SVG instead of showing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695409/nginx-offers-of-downoload-svg-instead-of-showing-it/3695579) for another question along the same lines.

Comment: How do I figure this out, just a point in the right direction is appreciated? My IT guy has not gotten back to me and most likely will not today.

Comment: You can use your browser's developer tools. For IE, press F12 to open them, switch to the network tab, start recording, then see what MIME type the `.svg` file comes down with (it'll be in detail view, under response headers). It's propably `application/octet-stream` which is browser-speak for `unrecognised binary blob`.

Comment: In chrome it does display it as `application/octet-stream`, is this something I can fix on the server or do I need my IT guy?

Comment: It depends on the server. If it's Apache, you can usually [use a .htaccess file to fix the problem](http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/gen/Configuring+MIME+Types+in+.htaccess). Sometimes a control panel is provided that'll let you change it. If it's IIS or something else, you'll probably need to speak to your IT people.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers don't allow the IMG tag to support SVG files, you can however put it in an object with an image as fallback in case the browser fails to render.

```
<object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="fallbackimage.jpg" />
</object>
```

Comment: The IMG tag does support SVG files. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: My bad, it is supported. But not by every browser, so it's best to use the OBJECT tag for a proper fallback.

Comment: Opera, Safari, Firefox, IE, Chrome all do so which one are you thinking of that doesn't?

Comment: IE 8.0 and below do not support SVG in IMG, and since there's still too many people using that browser you should make use of the fallback.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support SVG at all, IMG or otherwise.

Comment: That's why you put the SVG in a OBJECT with an IMG in it as fallback in case IE8 comes along so it falls back on the jpeg instead of the svg.

Comment: Because in 2020, someone would use IE8. First of all, if someone loads your website using IE8, the website won't display correctly in the first place. It may render so poorly as to make your website useless in IE8. So who cares if an SVG will load or not. Simply use a script to detect IE8 users and redirect them to https://chrome.google.com

Answer (score 0):

try use `<object data="/images/login_header.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>` instead

Comment: I was able to give this a try and it did not work as well. Instead of displaying nothing it just instantly starts a download for the image when you load the page.