# display images with fs.readfile in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple script that loads css for a home-made framework (I am not using express but just http)
my function is the following:

```
function getStatic(req, res) {

    console.log(req.params);
    if (fs.existsSync('./public/' + req.params.file)) {

        var file = fs.readFileSync('./public/' + req.params.file, 'utf8');


        res.write(file);
        res.end();

    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        });
        res.write("⚽⚽⚽⚽ 404 - not found ⚽⚽⚽⚽");
        console.log(req);
        res.end('error')
        console.log(req.params);

    }

}
```

Unfortunately images are presented as a file download. I found a similar answer here [nodejs - How to read and output jpg image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540978/nodejs-how-to-read-and-output-jpg-image) but I am not sure ow to integrated it in my code in a way that would cover jpg, png and possibly other image types ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image url downloads the image instead of displaying it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531061/image-url-downloads-the-image-instead-of-displaying-it)

Comment: I don't think that's the exactly approach, you can still get dynamically the content type with your code

Answer (score 0):

You must set content-type so the browser can properly process the requested file.

BTW there is a local file inclusion vulnerability, you can read more about that there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability

Comment: thanks for the information, so I think I need to use a different approach